# How to convert Spark Dense Vector to String and back to Vector in Scala?

Tags: scala, csv, apache-spark, export-to-csv

I have Dense Vector, I would like to convert vector into string (to save CSV) and convert string back to Dense Vector when load.

More detail

```
val dense_vec = Vectors.dense(1.0, 2.0, 3.0)
dense_vec: org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector = [1.0,2.0,3.0]

val str_dense_vec = dense_vec.toString
str_dense_vec: String = [1.0,2.0,3.0]
```

I want to convert `str_dense_vec` as type `String` into `org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create Double Array from String, then use `dense` method of `org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector`.

```
Vectors.dense(str_dense_vec.drop(1).dropRight(1).split(',').map(_.toDouble))
```

[link](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/mllib/linalg/Vectors.html) api.